# Why does LaTeX neither break at nor hyphenate after a "user kern"?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, hyphenation, kerning

When using the `\kern` command for user-defined kerns or the `\,` shorthand for small non-breaking spaces, this expands to a "userkern" node. At such nodes LaTeX doesn't break the line and the words following such nodes don't get hyphenated. Why is this?

I'm aware that it can be "fixed" by inserting `\hspace{0em}` (or by using a non-stretchable glue in the first place). But my question is: What is the rationale behind it?

Comment: essentially that is why TeX has kerns. if kerns acted as you suggest they would be the same as glue. note latex only uses glue for user defined lengths. if you used latex newlengrh, and hspace the issue would not arise

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There would still be the (significant) difference that a glue would always allow for a linebreak, while a kern only when it's a hyphenation point. Of course there is a need for non-breaking spaces, but I can't see why a kern should be non-breaking by default. If this is so obvious why are font kerns treated completely different than user kerns? (Font kerns, of course, allow for line breaks.) Even less do I understand the rational behind suppressing hyphenation for the following chars. A \kern in the middle of a word: First half gets hyphenated, second not. What is this good for?

Comment: well the distinction is slightly arbitrary, but the point remains that this is a tex feature that is not under latex control, and the only reason to have two types of nodes is to have an easy way of having some distiguishing features. As ever, the exact choice of which features, is a personal decision of D. Knuth, and guided by the implementation requirements of late 1970s hardware, so by now, it just is what it is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, I'm not complaining about it. I know how to help myself. It's that I am working on a package that provides some functionality in terms of kerns and glues. So I just liked to understand why the default behavior is like this. (Could have been that I'm missing something important.) If there are no really good reasons for it, that's an answer I can live with very well.

Answer (score 4):

Kerns are mostly used for correcting unsightly clashes between letters; for instance, the italic correction is a kern that can be used to break ligatures, where you usually don't want line breaks.

From the TeXbook (Chapter 14):

```
\danger Line breaks can occur only in certain places within a horizontal
list. Roughly speaking, they occur between words and after hyphens, but in
actuality they are permitted in the following five cases:\enddanger

\smallskip
\item{a)} at glue, provided that this glue is immediately preceded by a
non-discardable item, and that it is not part of a math formula (i.e., not
between math-on and math-off). A break ``at glue'' occurs at the left edge
of the glue space.

\smallskip
\item{b)} at a kern, provided that this kern is immediately followed by
glue, and that it is not part of a math formula.

\smallskip
\item{c)} at a math-off that is immediately followed by glue.

\smallskip
\item{d)} at a penalty (which might have been inserted automatically in a
formula).

\smallskip
\item{e)} at a discretionary break.
```

A kern neither marks a word boundary as far as hyphenation is concerned.

From the TeXbook (Appendix H):

```
\ddanger \TeX\ looks for potentially hyphenatable words by searching
ahead from each glue item that is not in a math formula. The search
bypasses characters whose |\lccode| is zero, or ligatures that begin
with such characters; it also bypasses whatsits and {\sl^{implicit kern}\/}
items, i.e., kerns that were inserted by \TeX\ itself because of information
stored with the font. If the search
finds a character with nonzero |\lccode|, or if it finds a ligature
that begins with such a character, that character is called the
{\sl starting letter}. But if any other type of item occurs before a suitable
starting letter is found, hyphenation is abandoned (until after the next
glue item). Thus, a box or rule or mark, or a kern that was explicitly
inserted by ^|\kern| or~|\/|, must not intervene between glue and a
hyphenatable word. If the starting letter is not lowercase (i.e.,
if it doesn't equal its own |\lccode|), hyphenation is abandoned unless
^|\uchyph| is positive.
```

So implicit kerns are bypassed as if they weren't present, but explicit kerns block further attempt to hyphenate.

If you want to specify a possible line break point you have to use a `\penalty` or glue.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is as good of an explanation as one can get from the TeXbook.

```
\ddanger According to the rules above, there's an important distinction
between implicit and explicit kerns, because \TeX\ recomputes implicit
kerns when it finds at least one hyphen point in a word. You can
see the difference between these two types of kerns when \TeX\ displays
lists of items in its ^{internal format}, if you look closely:
`|\kern2.0|' denotes an implicit kern of $2\pt$, and `|\kern 2.0|'
denotes an explicit kern of the same magnitude. The ^{italic correction}
command~|\/| inserts an explicit kern.
```